# Yes/No :Is $ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3] 2)$ a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}?$

Tags: field-theory

Is  $ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3] 2)$ is  a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}?$

My attempt : I think yes

By definition  of **normal extension** : $L/K$ is a normal extension if and only  if  for every irreducible  polynomial  $f \in K[x]$  with at least  one root in $L$

Now  i take $f(x)=x^3-2$ then $f(x)$ has one root i,e $x^3=2 \implies x=\sqrt[3] 2$

So here we have atleast one root in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: $L/K$ is a normal extension if and only if for every irreducible polynomial  $f \in K[x]$  with at least one root in $L$ must have all roots in $L$. $x^3-2$ does not have its non-real roots in $L$. So $L$ is not normal.